# d3 log scale always returning NaN

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to use log scale for y-axis of my line chart. The log scale just doesnt seem to work - it always returns NaN. Heres what I am trying:

[image]

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The domain should be an array.